# passing a dict of available classes to a function

Tags: python

I want to pass a dict with available classes to a function, so that I can construct them using their name, without importing them.

My idea was to do this:

```
from construct_classes import construct_classes

class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print('A')

class B:
    def __init__(self):
        print('B')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    construct_classes({'A': A, 'B': B})
```

And in construct_classes.py:

```
def construct_classes(my_classes):
    a = my_classes['A'].__init__(my_classes['A'])
    b = my_classes['B'].__init__(my_classes['B'])
```

This seems to work, but it looks hacky to me.

Are there any arguments against using this and if so is there another way to accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: *"so that I can construct them using their name, without importing them"* – And the point of that is?

Comment: Why are you passing the class as the first argument to `__init__`?

Comment: Just pass the class objects to the function instead of their names.

Comment: `a = my_classes['A'].__init__(my_classes['A'])` → `a = my_classes['A']()`

Comment: Sometimes there are valid use-cases to create a dictionary for classes in order to reference them by a dynamic string. But yours does not seem to be one of these cases.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Is the question formulated badly or is what I am doing a bad idea? The point is to achieve something like a "plugin" functionality. If you add another class to the dictionary you can get new functionalities in `construct_classes` without changing any code in `construct_classes`

Comment: The way you're currently writing it, `construct_classes` needs to very explicitly know that it expects an `A` and a `B`, even with hardcoded variable names `a` and `b`. Doesn't look like much of a plugin system at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I feel your question is about, this is what occurs to me:

If it looks hacky to you, maybe it is. But downvotes might have happened also because of the `__init__` call (follow Klaus comment fix).

I don't remember the use of expressions like "plug-ins map" or "plug-ins dict", although we know that creatures like that can exist. Now if you say the "list of installed plug-ins", that is another thing, if you see what I mean...

If you just want to add functionality without touching some class code, use a Decorator pattern (a Python decorator, that is).

If you are building a list of plug-ins for a user or client code to choose from and run, you need to abstract a common API for plugin management and use. So that you can choose from the list obtained with `.list()`, or iterate the list, and for example `.run()` any one of them.

Also check *namespace packages*. Don't think it applies directly here, but plug-ins seem mostly a name management issue, maybe you can structure your plug-ins ideas differently, and then make good use of that. They are just subfolders with common names and no `__init__.py`, bringing defined names/modules inside them into a common top name.